# How can I make this LINQ query cleaner?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, refactoring

I have recently written a LINQ query to get a `Dictionary` containing the last 6 month's placement amounts.

It is returning a `Dictionary` of Month string - Decimal Amount pairs.

It seems kind of cludgey.  Any of you LINQ masters out there able to help me refactor this to make a bit cleaner?

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the last 6 months of Placement History totalled by Month 
/// for all Agencies
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public Dictionary<string, decimal> getRecentPlacementHistory()
{
    var placementHistoryByMonth = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

    using (DemoLinqDataContext db = new DemoLinqDataContext())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Decimal monthTotal = 
              (from a in db.Accounts
               where 
                 (a.Date_Assigned.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month &&
                  a.Date_Assigned.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month)
               select a.Amount_Assigned).Sum();
            String currentMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MMM");

            placementHistoryByMonth.Add(currentMonth, monthTotal);
        }
        return placementHistoryByMonth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem:

```
where (a.Date_Assigned.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month &&
       a.Date_Assigned.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i).Month)
```

Shouldn't the latter expression end with .Year rather than .Month? Surely you'll rarely get a year with a value of 1-12...

I would extract the idea of the "current month" as you're using it a lot. Note that you're also taking the current time multiple times, which could give odd results if it runs at midnight at the end of a month...

```
public Dictionary<string, decimal> getRecentPlacementHistory()
{
    var placementHistoryByMonth = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    using (DemoLinqDataContext db = new DemoLinqDataContext())
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            DateTime selectedDate = now.AddMonths(-i);

            Decimal monthTotal = 
               (from a in db.Accounts
                where (a.Date_Assigned.Value.Month == selectedDate.Month &&
                       a.Date_Assigned.Value.Year == selectedDate.Year)
                select a.Amount_Assigned).Sum();

            placementHistoryByMonth.Add(selectedDate.ToString("MMM"),
                                        monthTotal);
        }
        return placementHistoryByMonth;
    }
}
```

I realise it's probably the loop that you were trying to get rid of. You could try working out the upper and lower bounds of the dates for the whole lot, then grouping by the year/month of `a.Date_Assigned` within the relevant bounds. It won't be much prettier though, to be honest. Mind you, that would only be one query to the database, if you could pull it off.

Comment: selectedDate.Month.Year doesn't make a lot of sense...typo? ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, How can I handle the situation where the Month is January.  Once we subtract months from the current date the year won't match anymore and this method will fail.  I'm trying to figure out how to get around that, while still not matching for EVERY January.

Comment: Yea, I was wondering about that.  He is using selectedDate.Month.Year to prevent getting data from all similar months throughout the years but if the date range loop subtracts enough months the year will change on him and it won't work.  How would you get around that?

Comment: Whoops, fixed to selectedDate.Year thanks. I don't see why this wouldn't work though - it should go back from January to the previous December... isn't that what you'd want?

Comment: For instance, today DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6) will give December 2008... at which point .Year will be 2008 and .Month will be 12.

Answer (score 2):

Use Group By

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime thisMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

Dictionary<string, decimal> dict;
using (DemoLinqDataContext db = new DemoLinqDataContext())
{
    var monthlyTotal = from a in db.Accounts
        where a.Date_Assigned > thisMonth.AddMonths(-6)
        group a by new {a.Date_Assigned.Year, a.Date_Assigned.Month} into g
        select new {Month = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
                    Total = g.Sum(a=>a.Amount_Assigned)};

    dict = monthlyTotal.OrderBy(p => p.Month).ToDictionary(n => n.Month.ToString("MMM"), n => n.Total);
}
```

No loop needed!

Comment: Nice!  It might be useful to group by (Year*100+Month).  Also, precompute "thisMonth.AddMonths(-6)"

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about missing months with no data,then I had a similar problem where I did the following : (translated to your variables)

```
  DateTime startPeriod = 
     new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-6);

  var query1 = from a in db.Accounts where a.Date_Assigned >= startPeriod
 group a by new { a.Date_Assigned.Year  ,a.Date_Assigned.Month  } into result
 select new
 {
     dt = new DateTime( result.Key.Year, result.Key.Month , 1),
     MonthTotal = result.Sum(i => i.Amount_Assigned)
 } ;             

  var dict = query1.OrderBy(p=> p.dt).ToDictionary(n => n.Dt.ToString("MMM") , n => n.MonthTotal );
```